# Unable to update Inner Arraylist object using Mongodb Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

I have below document structure in mongodb database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ec7b43e4b048cd48499b35"),
    "eidlist" : [
        {
            "eid" : "64286",
            "dst" : NumberLong(21044),
            "score" : 0
        },
        {
            "eid" : "65077",
            "dst" : NumberLong(21044),
            "score" : 0
        }
    ],
    "src" : NumberLong(21047)
}
```

I would like to update score field of first object using Java-mongodb driver:
I tried following code but it is not working :( :

```
  DBObject update_query=new BasicDBObject("src", key).append("eidlist.eid", e.getEdgeid());
  DBObject data=new BasicDBObject("$set",new BasicDBObject("eidlist.score",100));
 coll.update(update_query, data);
```

Please help me to solve this problem..I have checked all the parameter which I have passed to update function.I think something wrong with the update logic :(

Comment: did you run a findOne with the update query just to make sure you're getting the document you expect?

Comment: @adavis: Yes I tried with findOne and this record is exist in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You omiited the [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) from the update. Edit your code as shown.

```
DBObject data=new BasicDBObject("$set",new BasicDBObject("eidlist.$.score",100));
```

Comment: I am sorry your solution was right. I got the problem it's in data type. In database "eidlist.$.score" field is string and I am passing integer value in the update query.. :)

Comment: Aha. I was too quick and didn't look at that either. Good pick up.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this problem is:

```
DBObject data=new BasicDBObject("$set",new BasicDBObject("eidlist.$.score",""+100));
```

Ensure data type of every field used in the update query.It should be compatible with what we have stored in the mongodb :)